# Html special chars

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

I am using php. I have a problem with special chars. I have a word  for example it's. When i do encode in php side with

```
return htmlspecialchars($text,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
```

it is returning `it&#039;s` it is correct but browser does not decode it. So in browser it the same. Why does not browser decode that?

thanks

Comment: Look at the HTML source. Did it double-encode it as `&amp;#039;s`?

Comment: yeah it comes exact the same. I see it with firebug. When i cut that code then put back with firebug it becomes good.

Comment: Don't check in Firebug, check the **raw source**.

Comment: What's the browser interpreting the page as? If you're got a `Content-type: text/plain`, it will NOT be rendered as html.

Comment: it worked actually i was using framework. But it does not depend on that, i dunno when i changed some settings it worked. But it should not depend on framework :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested in IE 8

```
<?php
$text="It's";

echo htmlspecialchars($text,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
echo '<br><br>';

echo htmlspecialchars($text);

?>
```

Output:

It's

It's

source Output:

```
It&#039;s<br><br>It's
```

Maybe it's a browser setting???

Comment: I tried without ENT_QUOTES and without "UTF-8", but obviously it didn't work.